# Setting Role After Authentication SWING App. Not working As Expected

Tags: java, oracle, swing

Hello everyone I have SWING app. built using Netbeans 8.2 java 1.8.0_45
Connected to Oracle 11g.

The app is composed of 16 tabs. Each tab is connect to a different table and performs several functions (Add Record, update, Search, etc)

In my `DBConnection` class I'm trying to set User Role.

When I fire up the app, I got (Setting Role is not successful) message printed several times before the app connect. Which means it's working.

I get the same message printed while calling some of the functionalities in the app. Any one can tell me where I'm making mistake or how I can improve the class to get rid of this error?

Attached if the DBConnection Class.

```
public class DBConnection {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        ReadPropertyFile data = new ReadPropertyFile();
        DecryptCalss decr = new DecryptCalss();
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            //Getting connection info
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(data.getUrl(), data.getUser(), decr.decrypt(data.getEPassword()));         

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println("SQLException: Unable to open connection to db: " + sqle.getMessage());

            throw sqle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Exception: Unable to open connection to db: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
        try {
            String sql = "SET ROLE HIVP_WRITE";
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                out.println("Role successfully set");
            } else {
                out.println("Setting Role is not successful");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Error while setting role: " + e);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static void executeUpdate(String strQuery) throws Exception {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(strQuery);

        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println("SQLException: Unable to execute query : " + strQuery);
            throw sqle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Exception: Unable to execute query: " + e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    public static void executeQuery(String strQuery) throws Exception {
        try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(strQuery);
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println("SQLException: Unable to execute query : " + strQuery);
            throw sqle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("Exception: Unable to execute query: " + e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    //CLOSE CONNECTION
    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        try {
            if (conn != null && !conn.isClosed()) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            out.println("Error while closing connection: "+sqle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Solved the issue by surrounding the if Statement by while loop
try {
            String sql = "SET ROLE HIVP_WRITE";
            Statement stmt = null;
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (result.next()) {
                if (result.next()) {
                    out.println("ROLE SUCCESSFULLY SET");
                } else {
                    out.println("ROLE IS NOT SET");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.println("ERROR WHILE SETTING ROLE: " + e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the SQL statement returns an empty `ResultSet` and so, `result.next()` returns false.
The SQL **does** execute, but the ResultSet is simply empty.

If, for example, you will execute "select" statements, then the `ResultSet` will contain any data returned by the query.

The following `execute` methods are available and each functions as follows:

- `execute`: Returns true if the first object that the query returns is a ResultSet object. Use this method if the query could return one or more ResultSet objects. Retrieve the ResultSet objects returned from the query by repeatedly calling Statement.getResultSet.
- `executeQuery`: Returns one ResultSet object.
- `executeUpdate`: Returns an integer representing the number of rows affected by the SQL statement. Use this method if you are using INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE SQL statements.

This is further explained at an Oracle JDBC guide which is available here:
[Processing SQL Statements with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I fixed the problem by using while loop around the if statement.